# Getting Transaction Number from AdaptivePayments

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

This is an update to a previous question I had. Given that the entire problem of that question has changed, I felt it warranted a more accurate and detailed question. Here is my code:

## SetupPayment()

```
public PayResponse SetupPayment(string receiverEmail, decimal amountToPay)
{
    ReceiverList receiverList = new ReceiverList { receiver = new List<Receiver>() };
    Receiver receiver = new Receiver(amountToPay) { email = receiverEmail };
    receiverList.receiver.Add(receiver);

    RequestEnvelope requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("en_US");
    const string actionType = "CREATE";
    const string returnUrl = "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_implicit_payment/dotnet?success=true";
    const string cancelUrl = "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_implicit_payment/dotnet?cancel=true";
    const string currencyCode = "USD";

    PayRequest payRequest = new PayRequest(
        requestEnvelope,
        actionType,
        cancelUrl,
        currencyCode,
        receiverList,
        returnUrl)
    {
        senderEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPalSenderEmail"]
    };

    AdaptivePaymentsService adaptivePaymentService = new AdaptivePaymentsService(_payPalConfig);
    PayResponse payResponse = adaptivePaymentService.Pay(payRequest);

    return payResponse;
}
```

## ExecutePayment()

```
public ExecutePaymentResponse ExecutePayment(string payKey)
{
    RequestEnvelope requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("en_US");
    ExecutePaymentRequest executePaymentRequest = new ExecutePaymentRequest(requestEnvelope, payKey);
    AdaptivePaymentsService adaptivePaymentsService = new AdaptivePaymentsService(_payPalConfig);
    ExecutePaymentResponse executePaymentResponse = adaptivePaymentsService.ExecutePayment(executePaymentRequest);
    return executePaymentResponse;
}
```

## Calling Those Functions

```
PayResponse payResponse = payPalAdapter.SetupPayment(payPalUserEmail, commissionAmount);

if (payResponse.responseEnvelope.ack.ToString() == "SUCCESS")
{
    ExecutePaymentResponse executePaymentResponse = payPalAdapter.ExecutePayment(payResponse.payKey);
}
```

My question is - how can I retrieve the Transaction Number/ID of the payment that was created in `SetupPayment()` & executed in `ExecutePayment()`? The only mention of it I see in the Adaptive Payments API is saying that the transaction number is in the IPN Message...but is getting the transaction number really only possible through IPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call PaymentDetails after you execute the payment.  The response should have the transaction IDs (`paymentInfoList.paymentInfo(0).transactionId` for the receiver's transaction ID, or `paymentInfoList.paymentInfo(n).senderTransactionId` for the sender's transaction ID).

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for. But for some reason, the paymentDetailsResponse.paymentInfoList is null. Is there some way I need to request that data be populated specifically?

Comment: If the paymentInfoList is null, it might indicate that the buyer never completed the payment on PayPal.